# 401 invalid token / handler.xsrf_token does not match with the cookie

Tags: gramex

we are stuck in the dbauth module:

Symptoms:
While signup, the user is created BUT:

- The server does not send mail
- Response received is `401 Invalid Token`

Diagnosis Steps:

- Started with scratch
- Made a new Gramex project from scratch
- Populated the template `register.html`

```html
<form method="POST" action="" autocomplete="on" class="regForm">
  <div class="form-content">
    <div class="">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="hidden" name="_xsrf" value="{{ handler.xsrf_token }}">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" class="form-control" size="100" placeholder="Your First Name *" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" class="form-control" size="100" placeholder="Your Last Name *" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" name="user" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Your Email ID *" value="" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <select class="form-control" name="industry" id="industry">
              <option selected>Retail</option>
              <option>Energy and Resources</option>
              <option>Financial Services</option>
              <option>Transportation</option>
              <option>Others</option>
            </select>
          </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <button type="submit" class="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

- Made a minimal configuration with only one end point : `gramex.yaml`

```yaml
url:
  dbauthtest-login:
    pattern: /$YAMLURL/login/
    handler: DBAuth
    kwargs:
      template: $YAMLPATH/login.html
      url: $YAMLPATH/auth.csv
      # url: sqlite:///$YAMLPATH/auth.db
      user:
        column: user
        arg: user
      password:
        column: password
        arg: password
        # function: passlib.hash.sha256_crypt.encrypt(content, salt="wqertyuio")
      redirect:
        query: next
        url: /$YAMLURL/
      headers: &HEADERS
        X-Content-Type-Options: no sniff
        X-Frame-Options: DENY
        X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
        Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
      forgot:
        arg: email
        minutes_to_expiry: 1440
        email_from: gramex-guide-gmail # Name of the email service to use for sending emails
        email_column: user
        email_subject: Dell MIP Password Reset
        email_text: "
          Hi {name},\n
          \n
          You recently requested to reset your password for DELL MIP application.\
          Click on the link below to reset your password.
          \n
          Link: {reset_url}\n
          \n
          If you did not request a password change, please ignore the mail or reply back to the \
          same mail.\n
          Note: This above link will work only once and will expire in a day.
          \n
          \n
          For any other issues contact\n
          -bhasker.reddy@gramener.com\n
          -veera.balakrishnan@dell.com\n
          \n
          \n
          Thank You\n
          Team Dell MIP\n
          "
        template: $YAMLPATH/forgotpassword.html
      signup:
        template: $YAMLPATH/register.html
        columns:
          user: user
          fname: fname
          lname: lname
          industry: industry
        #   password: password
        # validate: galaxy.validate(args)
        minutes_to_expiry: 1440
        email_from: gramex-guide-gmail # Name of the email service to use for sending emails
        email_column: user
        email_subject: Galaxy Sign Up successful
        email_text: "
          Hi {name},\n
          \n
          Welcome to the Galaxy online portal! Below are your login credentials.
          \n
          Application Url: https://dellmi-uat.gramener.com
          \n
          Login ID: {user}
          \n
          Please set the password with this link: {reset_url}\n
          Note: This above link will work only once and will expire in a day.
          \n
          \n
          For any other issues contact\n
          -bhasker.reddy@gramener.com\n
          -veera.balakrishnan@dell.com\n
          Thank You\n
          Team Dell MIP
          "
    pool_pre_ping: True
    pool_recycle: 60
```

- `auth.csv` looks like

```
fname,lname,user,industry,password
```

- Tested

Findings:

- xsrf token (That is fetched from handler.xsrf_token and stored in the form in a hidden field) does not match the xsrf token in the cookie

Questions:

- Is there a simpler way?
- This issue is created even when we run the code copied from the documentation, So my guess is, this has something to do with generation of xsrf or may be session creation. Not sure, appreciate any inputs.
- Do we have another project that is running and available to refer?
- Do you have a direct solution to this?

Comment: Are you using Office 365 email when signing up? Could you please test with a Google personal account? That's because Office 365 scans the password reset link and invalidates it. I've faced this problem elsewhere.

Comment: Right now we are using `localauth` with `DBAuth` handler. So no SSO, no 365.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since user is created, there is no problem with xsrf token. Issue seems to be with sending mail. Make sure email service `gramex-guide-email` is defined.

`Invalid Token` error occurs when AuthHandler cannot find signup key.
In your `gramex.yaml`, update signup configuration to

```
signup:
  key: signup
  template: $YAMLPATH/register.html
  columns:
    user: user
    fname: fname
    lname: lname
    industry: industry
```

Comment: And making sure, address bar reads `/login/?signup` instead of `/login/?signup=true`, helped.